# Is there an existing CSS3 selector parser for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

Anybody know of snippet that will parse a CSS3 selector like this:

```
"form#network_template[method='put'][action='#form_{keyname}']"
```

to this:

```
{
  tag: "form",
  id: "network_template",
  method: "put",
  action: "#form_{keyname}"
}
```

or this:

```
<form id="network_template" method="put" action="#form_{keyname}">
```

Comment: what if there are descendants? or no tag specified?

Comment: I wrote a CSS3 selector parser that will parse this up nicely : [https://github.com/jdonaghue/LLSelectorParser](https://github.com/jdonaghue/LLSelectorParser) it is used in [Peppy](https://github.com/jdonaghue/Peppy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you meant to ask for a CSS3 selector *parser* in the title, [Slick](http://github.com/subtleGradient/slick), used in Mootools, may do the job; from the github page:

```
Slick.parse("h1, h2, ul > li, .things")

{
"raw": "h1, h2, ul > li, .things",
"expressions": [
    [{ "combinator":" ", "tag": "h1" }],
    [{ "combinator":" ", "tag": "h2" }],
    [{ "combinator":" ", "tag": "ul" }, { "combinator": ">", "tag": "li" }],
    [{ "combinator":" ", "tag": "*", "classList": ["things"], "classes": [{"value": "things", "regexp":RegExp }] }]
]
}
```

Mootools can also create an element with appropriate attributes straight from a selector.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to find, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) is used underneath jQuery. And there is also [Peppy](https://github.com/jdonaghue/Peppy). Newer versions have at least some CSS3 selector support. YMMV.

Google searches reveal interesting leads.

Comment: I wasn't looking for an engine, but a parser. Someone had "clarified" my title.

Comment: For reference: AFAIK Sizzle doesn't support all possible selectors - by design.